# How can you use a cursor on a nested object that first needs to be populated?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Say a there are two schemas: `User` and `Order`. The `User` schema has an attribute `Orders` which is an array of `Order` object ID's like the following:

```
Orders: [{
   ref: 'Order',
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
}]
```

How can I iterate through the a user's **populated** `Orders` with a cursor? Ideally I am looking for something like this:

```
User.find({ _id: userID }).
    .cursor('Orders')
    .eachAsync(async (order) => {
           // Do something with each order
    });
```

I want to use a cursor because all the orders can't fit in memory.

Alternative #2 that I've considered:

```
const user = await User.findById(userID);
Order.find({ _id: $in: user.Orders }).cursor().eachAsync(...);
```

Alternative #3 that I've considered:
Add a `UserID` field to the Order schema and do something like this:

```
const user = await User.findById(userID);
Order.find({ UserID: user._id }).cursor().eachAsync(...);
```

I'm just looking for the **most** efficient way to do these types of queries.

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on size of orders

1. if you expect tens of orders #1 will be efficient enough,
2. if greater than this #2 will be a more efficient approach provided
   UserID field in orders is indexed, also in this case you don't have
   to store individual orders in Orders array of User object.

See a nice explanation of your options [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

Alternatively you can use aggregation framework and do all this in a single operation but it will not be more efficient than either #2 or #3 unless you want to return orders of multiple users.